# groupby,count and having

Tags: count, group-by

I have a table like this

```
acct_no   code
==============
12        A  
12        B  
13        A  
14        Z  
15        w
```

There are also other columns in the table.

I am trying to find for which acct_no there are more than one code.
Like in the above 12 should be the result.

My query

```sql
Select acct_no,code,count(code)
from dbo.cas
group by acct_no
having count(code)>1
```

I want to know if this will work fine. The database is very large and the query is taking too much time to execute. I want it to be exactly correct.

Comment: Select acct_no,count(code) from dbo.cas group by acct_no having count(code)>1
I am using the above now. The previous query didn't work.Please help if this will work and if it is correct.